# Set page to display dropdown menu when editing data with PHP and MySQLi

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I have made a page for registering hardware, with 2 drop-down menus, which work.
The page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Registrer ny hardware</title>
</head>

<body>
Her registreres ny hardware. Udfyld formularen herunder og tryk gem. <br>

<form action="Registerhardware.php" method="post">
<!-- VARCHAR -->
    Serienr: <br>    
    <input type="text" name="Series"> <br>
<!-- VARCHAR -->
    Mærke: <br>

            <select id="Brand" name="Brand">

    <?php

          include('Mysql.php');

    $conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);

        if ($conn->connect_error)
        {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
    else
    $sql = "SELECT Brand FROM hardware";
    $result = $conn->query($sql); 

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())                                 
    {
            $Brand=$row["Brand"];
                echo "<option>
                    $Brand
                </option>";            
            }                
    ?>

        </select>
        <br>

<!--    <input type="text" name="Brand"> <br> -->
<!-- VARCHAR -->
    Model:  (* <a href=Registernymodel.php>Ny model - læg den ind her først</a>)<br>

        <select id="Model" name="Model">

    <?php

//          include('Mysql.php');

//  $conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);

        if ($conn->connect_error)
        {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
    else
    $sqlm = "SELECT Model FROM hardware";
    $resultm = $conn->query($sqlm); 

    while($rowm = $resultm->fetch_assoc())                                 
    {
            $Model=$rowm["Model"];
                echo "<option>
                    $Model
                </option>";            
            }                
    ?>

        </select>
        <br>
<!-- VARCHAR -->
    Detaljer: <br>
    <input type="text" name="Detaljer"> <br>
<!-- VARCHAR -->
    Indkøbsdato (yyyy-dd-mm): <br>
    <input type="date" name="Date"> <br>
<!-- VARCHAR -->
    Leverandør: <br>
    <input type="text" name="Firm"> <br>
<!-- VARCHAR -->
    Hardwarenavn: <br>
    <input type="text" name="Hardwarename"> <br>
<!-- VARCHAR -->
<!-- INT -->    
    Stregkode: <br>
    <input type="number" name="Barcode"> <br>
<!-- VARCHAR -->
    Placering: <br>
    <input type="text" name="Place"> <br><br>
<!-- ENUM -->
    SIMKort: <br>
    <input type="radio" name="SIMCard" value="Ja">Ja
    <input type="radio" name="SIMCard" value="Nej" checked>Nej<br><br>
<!-- ENUM -->
    På lager: <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Stock" value="Ja" checked>Ja
    <input type="radio" name="Stock" value="Nej">Nej<br><br>
<!-- ENUM -->
    Udlånes: <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Borrow" value="Ja" >Ja
    <input type="radio" name="Borrow" value="Nej" checked>Nej<br><br>
<!-- TEXT -->
    Kommentarer: <br>
    <textarea name="Comments" style="width: 200px; height: 50px;">    </textarea> <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Gem og send mail">    
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

But now I'm trying to edit data from one post in the table, but the first drop-down menu doesn't have any data and the form stops there.
The page looks like this:

```
    <?php
/*
Allows the user to both create new records and edit existing records
*/

// connect to the database
include("Mysql.php");

// creates the new/edit record form
// since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a     function that is easily reusable
function renderForm($Serienr = '', $Hardwarenavn ='', $error = '', $IDNr = '')
{ ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>
<?php if ($IDNr != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?    >
</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php if ($IDNr != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record";         } ?></h1>
<?php if ($error != '') {
echo "<div style='padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red'>" . $error
. "</div>";
} ?>

<form action="" method="post">
<div>
<?php if ($IDNr != '') { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="IDNr" value="<?php echo $IDNr; ?>" />
<p>IDNr: <?php echo $IDNr; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
<strong>IDNr: *</strong> <input type="text" name="IDNr"
value="<?php echo $IDNr; ?>"/><br/>

<strong>Serienummer: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Series"
value="<?php echo $Serienr; ?>"/><br/>
<strong>Mærke: *</strong>
            <select id="Brand" name="Brand">

    <?php

          include('Mysql.php');

    $conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);

        if ($conn->connect_error)
        {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
    else
    $sql = "SELECT Brand FROM hardware";
    $result = $conn->query($sql); 

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())                                 
    {
            $Brand=$row["Brand"];

                echo
                "<option>
                 $Brand
                </option>";            
            }                
    ?>

        </select>
        <br>

<br/>




<strong>Model: *</strong>


        <select id="Model" name="Model">

    <?php

//          include('Mysql.php');

//  $conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);

        if ($conn->connect_error)
        {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
    else
    $sqlm = "SELECT Model FROM hardware";
    $resultm = $conn->query($sqlm); 

    while($rowm = $resultm->fetch_assoc())                                 
    {
            $Model=$rowm["Model"];
                echo "<option>
                    $Model
                </option>";            
            }                
    ?>

        </select>
        <br>

<br/>
<strong>Detaljer: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Detaljer"
value="<?php echo $Detaljer; ?>"/><br/>
<strong>Dato: *</strong> <input type="date" name="Date"
value="<?php echo $Date; ?>"/><br/>
<strong>Leverandør: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Firm"
value="<?php echo $Firm; ?>"/><br/>
<strong>Hardwarenavn: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Hardwarename"
value="<?php echo $Hardwarenavn; ?>"/><br/>
<strong>Stregcode: *</strong> <input type="number" name="Barcode"
value="<?php echo $Barcode; ?>"/><br/>
<strong>Lokation: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Place"
value="<?php echo $Placering; ?>"/><br/>
<strong>SIMKort: *</strong> <input type="radio" name="SIMCard"
value="<?php echo $SIMKort; ?>"/><br/>
<strong>Lager: *</strong> <input type="radio" name="Stock"
value="<?php echo $Stock; ?>"/><br/>


<strong>Udlånes: *</strong> <input type="radio" name="Borrow"
value="<?php echo $Udlaan; ?>"/><br/>
<strong>Kommentarer: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Comments"
value="<?php echo $Kommentarer; ?>"/><br/>



<p>* required</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php }



/*

EDIT RECORD

*/
// if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a     record
if (isset($_GET['IDNr']))
{
// if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
if (is_numeric($_POST['IDNr']))
{

// get variables from the URL/form
$IDNr = $_POST['IDNr'];
$Serienr = htmlentities($_POST['Series'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Brand = htmlentities($_POST['Brand'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Model = htmlentities($_POST['Model'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Detaljer = htmlentities($_POST['Detaljer'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Date = htmlentities($_POST['Date'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Firm = htmlentities($_POST['Firm'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Hardwarenavn = htmlentities($_POST['Hardwarename'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Barcode = htmlentities($_POST['Barcode'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Placering = htmlentities($_POST['Place'], ENT_QUOTES);
$SIMKort = htmlentities($_POST['SIMCard'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Stock = htmlentities($_POST['Stock'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Udlaan = htmlentities($_POST['Borrow'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Kommentarer = htmlentities($_POST['Comments'], ENT_QUOTES);

// check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
if ($Serienr == '' || $Hardwarenavn == '')
{
// if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
renderForm($Serienr, $Hardwarenavn, $error, $IDNr);
}
else
{
// if everything is fine, update the record in the database
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE registrering SET Series = ?, Hardwarename = ?
WHERE IDNr=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $Serienr, $Hardwarenavn, $IDNr);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
// show an error message if the query has an error
else
{
echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
}

// redirect the user once the form is updated
header("Location: view.php");
}
}
// if the 'id' variable is not valid, show an error message
else
{
echo "Error!";
}
}
// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and     show the form
else
{
// make sure the 'id' value is valid
if (is_numeric($_GET['IDNr']) && $_GET['IDNr'] > 0)
{
// get 'id' from URL
$IDNr = $_GET['IDNr'];

// get the record from the database
 $conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database); 
if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM registrering WHERE IDNr=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("i", $IDNr);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($IDNr, $Serienr, $Brand, $Model, $Detaljer, $Date, $Firm,     $Hardwarenavn, $Barcode, $Placering, $SIMKort, $Stock, $Udlaan, $Kommentarer);
$stmt->fetch();

// show the form
renderForm($Serienr, $Hardwarenavn, NULL, $IDNr);

$stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else
{
echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
}
}
// if the 'id' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the view.php     page
else
{
header("Location: view.php");
}
}
}



/*

NEW RECORD:

*/
// if the 'id' variable is not set in the URL, we must be creating a new record
else
{
// if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// get the form data
$IDNr = $_POST['IDNr'];
$Serienr = htmlentities($_POST['Series'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Brand = htmlentities($_POST['Brand'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Model = htmlentities($_POST['Model'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Detaljer = htmlentities($_POST['Detaljer'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Date = htmlentities($_POST['Date'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Firm = htmlentities($_POST['Firm'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Hardwarenavn = htmlentities($_POST['Hardwarename'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Barcode = htmlentities($_POST['Barcode'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Placering = htmlentities($_POST['Place'], ENT_QUOTES);
$SIMKort = htmlentities($_POST['SIMCard'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Stock = htmlentities($_POST['Stock'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Udlaan = htmlentities($_POST['Borrow'], ENT_QUOTES);
$Kommentarer = htmlentities($_POST['Comments'], ENT_QUOTES);

// check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
if ($Serienr == '' || $Hardwarenavn == '')
{
// if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
renderForm($Serienr, $Hardwarenavn, $error);
}
else
{
// insert the new record into the database
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT rgistrering (Series, Hardwarename) VALUES     (?, ?)"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $Serienr, $Hardwarenavn);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else
{
echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
}

// redirec the user
header("Location: view.php");
}

}
// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
else
{
renderForm();
}
}

// close the mysqli connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please ask precise question.

Comment: Okay. My Question is: When I want to edit a post, I want the 2 dropdown menues to display the value, that was chosen when the hardware was registered. Right know I can't even get it to show any values in the dropdown menues. Please help!

Comment: That means, at edit mode, first drop down is not populated, right? And if yes then please do html inspect by your browser and check if there is any error occurred. Please post your error here also. If you dont see error there, can you please share the two table schema here?